# Error -Login failed for user 'XXXX' azure SQL server database

Tags: django, python-3.x, azure, azure-sql-server, azure-webapps

I have a Python 3.6 Django azure web app, i am using Azure sql server database.

For few months the user gets the following error:

('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'XXXX'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'XXX'. (18456)")

I tried several solutions non of them worked, yesterday i decided to set audit log on the database , and when looking in the logs i see the following error:

Err 2812, Level 16, Server XXXX
Could not find stored procedure 'sp_cloud_connection_set_sds'.

I am not familiar with this store procedure and not sure why it tries to run it, any ideas on how to solve it?

Thanks,

Nir

Comment: Does the user "xxx" can connect to the Azure SQL database with SSMS?

Comment: Yes, sure, and there error doesn't happens all the time, it happens from time to time , no specific pattern

Comment: Likely a transient error.  You can try implementing a retry logic like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41473137/pyodbc-how-to-retry-to-recover-from-transient-errors

Comment: Thanks, i open a support request for Azure team , i will wait for their respond.